# How to Programmatically activate an entry in the SettingsPane?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a SettingsPane that I populate with a few commands.

I can activate the SettingPane programmatically:

```
if ( Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value != Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Snapped )
{
  SettingsPane.Show();
}
```

1. How can I programmatically activate a command in the SettingsPane?
2. How can I programmatically get a list of the commands in the SettingsPane?

Thanks,
 EitanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way, but given for each command you provide the callback when that command is activated I can't see any reason why you can't execute that yourself instead.

You made to do some extra work to make it seem seamless such as showing the settings pane when they dismiss your manually shown settings view.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to give the user the impression that the setting panel is open. and I thought it would look nice to do it like this.
My SettingPanel commands are User Controls that popup.
Thanks,
EitanB